# sending lots of AWS SQS messages---FAST

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-sqs

I have an application that may need to send hundreds of thousands of messages each run of my program using SQS. The program takes 1-2 hours/run and I run it 5-10 times/day. So that's roughly 1 million messages/day.

I want to do it fast. Is my best approach to:

1. Send each with its own send-message, but send them in another thread so my main thread doesn't pause?
2. Use send-message-batch, which lets me send 10 messages at a time?
3. OMG. Why am I sending so many messages? Why not write them all into a big object, save the object in S3, and then send a pointer to the object with SQS?

My messages are the stdout and stderr of programs that are running in a distributed system. So the problem with #3 above is that I won't get the output of the program until the batching happens. I suppose that I could batch up every 60 seconds.

I'm sure that this has come up for other people. Is there a clever way to do this in the AWS SQS API that I am missing?

Kinesis is not an option in my environment.

We are currently sending the messages from python programs running on Apache Spark workers---about 2000 cores/cluster---and other monitoring systems and about 5-20 clusters. The messages will go to a lambda server. The problem is that some of the nodes send a few thousand messages within the course of 10-20 seconds

We tried using Spark itself to collect this information, storing it in an RDD, saving that RDD in S3, and so on. The problem with that approach was that we didn't get real-time monitoring, and we added several hours to processing time. (We're not entirely sure why it added so much time, but it's possible that Spark ended up re-computing some RDDs because some stuff would no longer fit in RAM or on the spill disks.)

Comment: Have you considered Kinesis? You can batch up to 500 msg in one api call.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not an option.

Comment: You invariably need to batch at some level.  If for no other reason than doing something like sending hundreds of thousands of messages every minute will be costly, to put it mildly.

Comment: AWS SQS costs 40 cents to send a million messages. How is that costly?  I'm sending hundreds of thousands of messages a day.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were talking about per minute or faster, 100k messages a day isn't a huge deal, as you say.

Comment: How are you managing the distributed proceses and capturing their output?

Comment: We are sending the messages from python programs running on Apache Spark workers---about 2000 cores/cluster---and other monitoring systems and about 5-20 clusters. The messages will go to a lambda server. The problem is that some of the nodes send a few thousand messages within the course of 10-20 seconds.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of putting that comment into the question body, and adding Spark tags, since that's an important point. I'm not familiar with Spark (outside of running some examples), but my first thought is to use [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/) to collect the standard output/error and package it for SQS, perhaps with [SNS](https://github.com/miyagawa/fluent-plugin-amazon_sns) as an intermediary. That may or may not work for you, and without knowing a lot more about your deployment I couldn't tell you how to install, so not an answer.

Comment: You might also consider switching from StdOut/StdErr to the Python logging module. According to [this](https://medium.com/@shantanualshi/logging-in-pyspark-36b0bd4dec55) it's simple to configure logging for PySpark (I guess it uses Jython under the hood?). You could send the logging output to SysLog with one of the built-in appenders, and configure Fluentd to listen on the syslog port. Or use an HTTP appender, or look for a third-party Fluentd appender.

Comment: Thanks. We're currently using syslog. The problem is that we are losing messages with UDP and with TCP we soak the server. SQS is the functionality that we want.

Comment: [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/) looks exciting, but it's too heavyweight for our environment. We are running on Amazon EMR and trying to migrate from our Apache-based monitoring system to something entirely residing in Lambda.

Comment: *"AWS SQS costs 40 cents to send a million messages."* — this is highly inaccurate. It's 40 cents per million _requests_. You need 3 requests (at least) to work with SQS: send, receive, delete. They all count as "requests". Also, a batch send of 10 messages is _one_ request. So by batching 10 messages at a time, and ensuring that you never need to retry anything, you'll effectively be paying for 30k requests per day (10k send with 10 messages each, 10k receive, 10k delete). Either way, not very expensive. The amount of messages you're dealing with is really trivial for SQS.

Comment: @Parsifal - if you turn your comment into an answer, I can respond to it. However, Spark uses py4j to communicate with a separate Python process. We used `logging` and had it go to Syslog initially, but we lost messages (with UDP) or surged the server (with TCP).

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with Spark (or modern EMR), so don't have an actual answer for you; I'm just throwing out ideas. If you're set on using SQS, then I think you'll have to insert yourself into the logging framework. Maybe that happens at the Python level (but I doubt that you want to make synchronous calls to SQS in the middle of your processing), maybe it happens in the Hadoop framework, maybe it happens at the OS level.

Comment: I will leave you with one more idea: if your problem with syslog is that you're swamping a single remote syslogd, does it work to have multiple syslogd instances and use a network load balancer to spread traffic? The problem with this approach is that you can end up with out-of-order messages, but as long as everything is timestamped and tagged with its source you should be able to re-order.

Comment: @vy32 Any joy by 2022? :/

Comment: @jtlz2 - Thanks for the nudge. I posted and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this problem three ways:

1. We created work queue with a consumer running in a separate queue. The consumer received messages from the worker and sent them off in batches of 10. If no message was received within a few seconds, the queue was flushed.

The full code is here: https://github.com/uscensusbureau/DAS_2020_Redistricting_Production_Code/blob/5e619a4b719284ad6af91e85e0548077ce3bfed7/source/programs/dashboard.py

The relevant class is below.

```
#
# We use a worker running in another thread to collect SQS messages
# and send them asychronously to the SQS in batches of 10 (or when WATCH_TIME expires.)
#

def sqs_queue():
    return boto3.resource('sqs',
                          config = botocore.config.Config(
                              proxies={'https':bcc_https_proxy().replace("https://","")}
                          )).Queue(das_sqs_url())

SQS_MAX_MESSAGES=10             # SQS allows sending up to 10 messages at a time
WATCHER_TIME=5                  # how long to collect SQS messages before sending them
EXIT='exit'                     # token message to send when program exits


# SQS Worker. Collects
class SQS_Client(metaclass=Singleton):
    """SQS_Client class is a singleton.
    This uses a python queue to batch up messages that are send to the AWS Quwue.
    We batch up to 10 messages a time, but send every message within 5 seconds.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Set up the singleton by:
        - getting a handle to the SQS queue through the BCC proxy.
        - Creating the python queue for batching the requests to the SQS queue.
        - Creating a background process to flush the queue every 5 seconds.
        """
        # Set the default
        if TRY_SQS_SECOND not in os.environ:
            os.environ[TRY_SQS_SECOND]=YES

        self.sqs_queue = sqs_queue()  # queue to send this to SQS
        self.pyqueue  = queue.Queue() # producer/consumer queue used by dashboard.py
        self.worker = threading.Thread(target=self.watcher, daemon=True)
        self.worker.start()
        atexit.register(self.terminate)

    def flush(self, timeout=0.0):
        """Flush the pyqueue. Can be called from the main thread or the watcher thread.
        While there are messages in the queue, grab up to 10, then send them to the sqs_queue.
        Returns last message processed, which may be EXIT.
        The watcher repeatedly calls flush() until it receives an Exit.
        """
        entries = []
        msg     = None
        t0      = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.pyqueue.get(timeout=timeout, block=True)
            except queue.Empty as e:
                break
            if msg==EXIT:
                break
            msg['Id'] = str( len( entries ))
            entries.append(msg)
            if len(entries)==SQS_MAX_MESSAGES:
                break
            if time.time() - t0 > timeout:
                break
        if entries:
            # Send the 1-10 messages.
            # If this fails, just save them in S3.
            try:
                if os.getenv(TRY_SQS_SECOND)==YES:
                    self.sqs_queue.send_messages(Entries=entries)
                    entries = []
            except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as err:
                logging.warning("Cannot send by SQS; sending by S3")
                os.environ[TRY_SQS_SECOND]=NO
        if entries:
            assert os.getenv(TRY_SQS_SECOND)==NO # should have only gotten here if we failed above
            for entry in entries:
                send_message_s3(entry['MessageBody'])
        return msg

    def watcher(self):
        """Repeatedly call flush().
        If the flush gets exit, it returns EXIT and we EXIT.
        """
        while True:
            if self.flush(timeout=WATCHER_TIME)==EXIT:
                return

    def queue_message(self, *, MessageBody, **kwargs):
        self.pyqueue.put({'MessageBody':MessageBody})

    def terminate(self):
        """Tell the watcher to exit"""
        self.flush()
        self.pyqueue.put(EXIT)
```

However, we were still unsatisfied with this, as emptying the SQS queue was also slow, and there is poor visibility into the queues.

2. We developed a system that used S3 as a message queue. Create objects with a given bucket and prefix and then a random string, and then remove them in the consumer. Different consumers used different prefixes of the random string.
3. We implemented a traditional system with HTTP REST and with the python server running under `mod_wsgi`. This was the most performant.